# How to convert a flat array into a tree array based on dot notation and "type" attribute?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to convert a flat array below:

```
$array = [
   [
    "hierarchy" => "1",
    "title" => "Fruits",
    "type" => "category_label"
   ],
   [
    "hierarchy" => "1.1",
    "title" => "Citruses",
    "type" => "category_label"
   ],
   [
    "hierarchy" => "1.1.1",
    "title" => "Orange",
    "type" => "item"
   ],
   [
    "hierarchy" => "1.1",
    "title" => "Mango",
    "type" => "item"
   ],
   [
    "hierarchy" => "1.2",
    "title" => "Grape",
    "type" => "item"
   ]
];
```

As you can see from above, it has two hierarchical, dot-notation string "1.1", therefore I use the "type" attribute to differentiate them.

What the result I'm expecting:

```
/*
1. Fruits
-  1.1. Citruses
--- 1.1.1. Orange
-- 1.1. Mango
-- 1.2. Grape
*/
```

```
//Desired result
[
    "hierarchy" => "1",
    "title" => "Fruits",
    "type" => "category_label",
    "children" => [
        [
            "hierarchy" => "1.1",
            "title" => "Citruses",
            "type" => "category_label"
            "children" => [
                [
                    "hierarchy" => "1.1.1",
                    "title" => "Orange",
                    "type" => "item"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            "hierarchy" => "1.1",
            "title" => "Mango",
            "type" => "item"
        ],
        [
            "hierarchy" => "1.2",
            "title" => "Grape",
            "type" => "item"
        ]
    ]
];
```

Using approach as described in [How to build a tree from a concatenated string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288536/how-to-build-a-tree-from-a-concatenated-string-in-php) I can't achieve my desired result.
What I can do now?

Comment: Could you share what you tried using a demo link? Sorting the array making parents come before child is a good start.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code you've currently tried, and the output or error message it gives.

Comment: In your example. Let say that "Mango" becomes a "category_label": how can you determine where "Orange" goes?

Answer (score 1):

You could first key all items by their hierarchy in a new associative array. Then iterate the items again, and remove the last part of the `hierarchy` to get the key of the parent item, locate it in that new associative array, and add it to its children. If it does not have a parent, add it to the result array.

Since your `hierarchy` delimiter is a point, you can use the `pathinfo` function to remove the last "extension" from it:

It turns out your hierarchy numbering is not unique (e.g. "1.1"). If it is intended that parent nodes can have the same number as a sibling of type "item", but that two nodes of the *same* type will never have the same hierarchy, then key the nodes by the combination of type and hierarchy:

```
foreach ($array as $item) $keyed[$item["type"] . $item["hierarchy"]] = $item;

foreach ($keyed as &$item) {
    $parent = pathinfo($item["hierarchy"], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    if ($parent == $item["hierarchy"]) $result[] =& $item;
    else $keyed["category_label$parent"]["children"][] =& $item;
}
```

After running this, `$result` will have the desired structure.

I would however suggest to make the hierarchy codes unique, so they don't clash across types. Then the above code can be changed to:

```
foreach ($array as $item) $keyed[$item["hierarchy"]] = $item;

foreach ($keyed as &$item) {
    $parent = pathinfo($item["hierarchy"], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    if ($parent == $item["hierarchy"]) $result[] =& $item;
    else $keyed[$parent]["children"][] =& $item;
}
```

Comment: Im impressed. But its missing `Citruses` `category_label` `1.1` EDIT: i guess it got overwritten by `Mango` `1.1`

Comment: I see, so `hierarchy` is not a unique reference? How should it be interpreted? Will it always only consist of the number 1 with dots, never any other number?

Comment: As i see he can has many of any. So `Fruits` is hierarchy `1`, and  i guess there could also be `Buildings` with hierarchy `1` too. And same for children.

Comment: The Asker should answer really to this.

Comment: It could work if you use `hierarchy` AND `title` in `$parent`

Comment: @trincot, the provided example is not logical. It has to be clarified to go further.

Comment: Anyway I have updated the answer with an assumption about the duplicates. Still Asker should clarify what makes a reference unique.

Answer (score 0):

See if this logic helps, I will try to edit the answer and explain within 1 day.

```php
$tree_array = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(count(explode('.',$value['hierarchy']) == 1){
        array_push($array_tree, $value)
    }
}

foreach($array as $value){
    if(count(explode('.',$value['hierarchy'])) == 2){
        if($value['type'] == 'category_label'){
            foreach($array_tree as $key =>  $tree){
                if($tree['hierarchy'] == explode('.',$value['hierarchy'])[0]){
                    array_push($array_tree['children'],$value);
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach($array_tree as $key =>  $tree){
                if($tree['hierarchy'] == explode('.',$value['hierarchy'])[0]){
                    array_push($array_tree[$key],$value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach($array as $value){
    if(count(explode('.',$value['hierarchy'])) == 3){
        if($value['type'] == 'item'){
            foreach($array_tree as $key => $tree){
                foreach($tree as $item){
                    if($item['hierarchy'] == explode('.',$value['hierarchy'],2)[1]){
                        array_push($array_tree[$key]['children'],$value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```